# How can i handle different responses in REST?

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I have 2 entities. But my response type doesn't fit with the Entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private boolean available;

@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
private List<Product> products;


public Customer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public Customer(String firstname, String lastname, boolean available) {
    super();
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.available = available;
}


public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}


public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}


public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}


public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}


public boolean isAvailable() {
    return available;
}

public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
    this.available = available;
}

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void addProduct(Product product) {
if(products==null)
    products=new LinkedList<Product>();
    products.add(product);
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer [id=" + id + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname
            + ", available=" + available + "]";
}

}
```

[GET] localhost:8080/myapp/customers/{id}
Here i want to take customers' all data (id,firstname,lastname,available,products)

```
{
"id" : 1,
"name" : "John",
"lastname" : "Doe",
"available" : false
"products" : {...}
}
```

[GET] localhost:8080/myapp/customers
But here i want to take customers some data (just id,firstname,lastname)

```
[{
"id" : 1,
"name" : "John",
"lastname" : "Doe",
},
{
"id" : 2,
"name" : "Alex",
"lastname" : "Adams",
}]
```

Should i create new classes for each response? or edit json data in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should segregate:

- Entities are used for database operations
- DTOs are used for communication with other services

So in your case I'll suggest you to create DTOs to handle that situation. Note that there are many libraries which make easier the conversion between DTOs and Entities, example ModelMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single Response DTO.
Example:

Response type of this could be `CustomerDTO`

```
[GET] localhost:8080/myapp/customers/{id}
```

And response type of below API could be `List<CustomerDTO>`

```
[GET] localhost:8080/myapp/customers
```